# Passing slug into ListView URL

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I wanted to pass slug into ListView. But it was not as simple as passing it to DetailView.

That's because, ListView doesn't have built-in slug support.

I found answer of my question and I want to share with you, guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: I use ManyToMany field.

Models.py:

```
class Article(models.Model):
    ...
    country = models.ManyToManyField('Country', related_name='country', blank=True)
    ...

class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('<country>/', ArticlesListView.as_view(), name='articles-list'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_list_or_404
class ArticlesListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'articles/articles-list.html'


    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return get_list_or_404(Article.objects.all().filter(topic__slug = self.kwargs['topic']))
```

Reference link:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering